# НЕ с прилагательными и причастиями

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

Примеры:

1. На нем даже брюки были неглажеНые. На нем даже брюки были не глажены.

"НеглажеНые" здесь прилагательное от глагола несовершенного вида (НЕ - слитно и одно Н ?)  А "не глажены" получается краткое причастие (НЕ пишется раздельно?) или как?

2. Стены в доме были непрокрашеННые. Стены в доме были не прокрашены.

Прокрасить - глагол совершенного вида. НЕ -слитно или раздельно?

3. Стены в доме были недокрашенные. Стены в доме были не докрашены. (здесь как быть?)
4. Я зашел в комнату и увидел висящие на спинке стула неглажеНые брюки.

Или "неглажеННые" ?  Запятая после "стула" нужна ?

Answer (score 1):

Причастия глаголов несовешенного вида и соотносительные с ними прилагательные(**они образуются только от бесприставочных глаголов)**  пишутся по-разному: причастия с нн, прилагательные — с одним н, напр.: глаженный и глаженый. Не с краткими причастиями пишется раздельно. Не с отглагольными прилагательными слитно (о раздельном написании см. справочник).

> 1) На нем даже брюки были неглаже***Н***ые.
>
> 2)Стены в доме были ***не***прокрашеННые. Стены в доме были не прокрашены. В первом случае два н. Есть приставка ***про***. Не пишется слитно.
>
> 3)Недокраше***нн***ый - ***два н***. Влияние приставки недо. Но: недокрашены( неполнота действия). Не докрашены ( действие не доведено до конца).
>
> 4)Я зашел в комнату и увидел висящие на спинке стула неглажеНые брюки. Одно н. Прилагательное. Но: не глаже**нн**ые со вчерашнего дня брюки. Причастие. Есть зависимое слово.

Оснований для постановки для запятой нет.

Comment: Серж,  вот интересно: стираный-перестираный, но недоваренный. Получается, что для приставки ПЕРЕ учитываем значение многократности действия, а для приставки НЕДО значение неполноты действия не учитывается?

Comment: Вера, в правилах так сказано: пишутся с н сочетания-повторы с приставкой пере- во второй части, имеющие усилительное значение. В них вторая часть пишется так же, как первая (с нн или н), напр.:стираный-перестираный. Но: перестиранный. В первом случае, видимо, не учитывается многократность. Ведь говорится: **имеет усилительное значение**.

Comment: Правила не совсем логичны. Стираный-перестираный - здесь ПЕРЕ со значением избыточного признака. Понятно, почему приставка НЕ и ПЕРЕ (со значением многократности/избыточности) не меняют количество Н: слово по-прежнему остается ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫМ, нет перехода в причастие. А вот "недоваренный картофель (сырой)" - это же качественный признак, тогда это прилагательное или причастие?

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь надо исходить из смысла. При причастии мыслится деятель в творительном падеже.  Здесь, на мой взгляд, нельзя подставить сущ-е в творительном падеже. Поэтому прилагательное. Высокая степень качества.

Comment: Каша недоварена, яичница пережарена - явные прилагательные, но в полной форме пишется НН (недоваренный, пережаренный), то есть учитывается наличие приставки при выборе НН. Но почему тогда не учитывается наличие приставок НЕ и ПЕРЕ в прилагательных "некрашеный" и "стираный-перестираный"?

Answer (score 1):

1) На нем даже брюки были неглажеНые (прилагательное).

На нем даже брюки были не глажены. Стилистическая неточность для причастия, получается: гладить брюки на нем.

2) Стены в доме были непрокрашеННые. Стены в доме были не прокрашены.
Стены в доме были недокрашенные. Стены в доме были не докрашены. Здесь полные и краткие причастия.

3) Я зашел в комнату и увидел висящие на спинке стула неглажеНые брюки. Прилагательное (Н), нет запятой, неоднородые отношения (причастный оборот перед прилагательным).